# The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed

Tags: asp.net

Hi I am using sql server fulll edition.

any idea how should I solve this issue, I search on net but not found any helpful answer.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this link - http://forums.asp.net/t/913172.aspx

Answer (score 55, accepted):

SQL Server 2005(Full Version) does not support the "user instance"(automatic creation of databases from code) directive in the connection string.  Its a feature of sql server express edition.

Also if your connection string has user Instance attribute, then try removing  the "User Instance=True;"

Comment: that's true! Working great!

Comment: This was it: try removing the "User Instance=True;"

Comment: +1. I it worked when I switched to SQL Express.  But if I've to make it work with my server or full edition, I'm unable to find the place where I can edit/remove this attribute. I don't know where does LINQPad stores its connection string or if there is really a way to edit it in the tool? I observed two files namely "LINQPad.exe.config" and "LPRun.exe.config" in the installation directory of LINQPad but to no avail.

Answer (score 5):

Automatic creation of databases from code is a feature of the SQL Express Edition. Try modifying your connection string after having manually created the `FOO` database:

```
server=SERVERNAME;database=FOO;uid=sa;pwd=
```

Answer (score 3):

User instancing is a feature of Sql Express only and is not available in full Sql Server.  You need to construct your connection string to point at the DB server without any USer Instancing defined

Answer (score 1):

User Instancing (which allows the automatic creation of databases from code) is not supported on the full version of SQL Server, only on the Express version.

> The solution is to manually create the
>   database in SQL Server and set the
>   connection string to point to it.  You
>   will also need to run
>   `aspnet_regsql.exe` manually against
>   the database if you will be using any
>   of the new built-in database features
>   of ASP.NET v2.0.

[Ref](http://forums.asp.net/t/913172.aspx).