# The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed, in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5

I have upgraded my OS to Windows 10 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition.

Now I am getting error "**The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.**" as I have search all the link and followed all the step but not getting rid of this error.

As I don't have any `user instance =....` in my connection string.

I have gone through the following links as well

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8525a00a-d6ea-4630-94ef-fefbce198b62/the-user-instance-login-flag-is-not-supported-on-this-version-of-sql-server-the-connection-will-be?forum=sqlexpress
http://codeverge.com/asp.net.installation-setup/the-user-instance-login-flag-is-no/288955
http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sqlserver/sqlexpress.aspx?ID=8525a00a-d6ea-4630-94ef-fefbce198b62 
[The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641671/the-user-instance-login-flag-is-not-supported-on-this-version-of-sql-server-the)

Comment: Have you checked how your connection string looks like, exactly?

Comment: Thanks Roger Wolf for your suggestion but my connection string doesn't contain any user instance word in it. '<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=KlathrateUserDB;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />'

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config file.
I had faced similar issue
but got it sorted after making changes in Connection String in web.config file

Comment: This should have been a comment, rather than an answer.