# Login failed for user

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870126/sql-server-2008-to-sql-server-2005)

Hi all:

I get this error in visual studio 2008 server explorer when i click the aspnet db in MVC 1 application:

> The database
>   'D:\Myproj\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF'
>   cannot be opened because it is version
>   661. This server supports version 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not
>   supported. Cannot open user default
>   database. Login failed. Login failed
>   for user 'Sparrow-VAIO\Sparrow'.

Please suggest solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870126/sql-server-2008-to-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 2):

looks like you need to install the 2008 R2 version of SQL (or Express). heres the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/)

EDIT: looks like the server explorer in VS 2008 isnt up to par with the databse file tha you have.  is moving to VS 2010 is an option ? if not you can attach the database file to the R2 instance you have installed and access the database using a standard connection string.

Comment: I have already installed SQL server R2 and given its name in Web.config

Comment: is it possible for you to use VS 2010 ? alternativly can you attach the database to the SQL insatnce and use a connection string like `Server=MyServer;DataBase=DBName;Integrated Security=True` instead of the direct file connection ?